# GAE: Why there is a constant POST request to /RPC2

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to Google app engine not new to Python, there is a very confusing problem to me.

First of all, show you my version.

[image]

The problem is when I run the development server, there is a constant POST request to /PRC2, I have no idea where it came from.

See the screenshot below.
[image]

My main.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import os
from handlers import MainHandler


CURRENT_VERSION_ID = os.environ.get('CURRENT_VERSION_ID', None)

if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    DEVELOPMENT = False
else:
    DEVELOPMENT = True


config = {
    'DEBUG': DEVELOPMENT
}


routes = [
    (r'/', MainHandler),    # Homepage
]

app = webapp.WSGIApplication(
    routes, debug=DEVELOPMENT, config=config
)
```

And app.yaml

```
application: xxxxxxxxxxxx
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange. Try another port and look if you keep this strange POST. Or serve the post in your app and look what is in the request, to find out where it comes from.

Comment: Hi, I changed to port 8000 and this issue is gone. But I worried if this is because I use windows8, will investigate tonight.

Comment: I agree with dragonx that this strange post comes from an XML-RPC resource. I suggest you investigate the payload : self.request.body

Comment: Thanks both of you, I figured out that this is because of the the build agent I used, somehow it keeps posting something. After I stop the service, the issue is completely gone.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably launching dev_appserver on some port where an XML-RPC application is looking for a particular API.